# Debugging a subprocess.Popen call

Tags: python, subprocess

I have been using `subprocess.Popen` successfully in the past, when wrapping binaries with a python script to format arguments / customize etc...

Developing a nth wrapper, I did as usual... but nothing happens.

Here is the little code:

```
print command
p = subprocess.Popen(command, shell = True)
result = p.communicate()[0]
print vars(p)
return result
```

And here is the output:

```
/usr/bin/sh /tmp/run/launch.sh
{'_child_created': True, 'returncode': 0, 'stdout': None, 'stdin': None, 'pid': 21650, 'stderr': None, 'universal_newlines': False}
```

As you can see, the goal is to create a shell script setting up everything I need, and then executing it. I would prefer to use real python code, but unfortunately `launch.sh` call 3rd party shell scripts that I have no wish to try and replicate (though I've been insisting for a python api for over a year now).

The problem is that:

- the shell script is not executed (it should spawn process and output some little things)
- no python exception is raised
- there is nothing in the `p` object that indicates that an error occurred

I have tried `check_call` without any success either...

I am at a loss regarding what I should do, and would be very glad if someone could either point my mistake or direct me toward resolution...

**EDIT:**

- Trying to run this on Linux (sh)
- shell is necessary for variable substitution in the scripts invoked

**EDIT 2:**

Following `badp` suggestion, I tweaked the code and added

```
subprocess.Popen('ps', shell = True).communicate()
```

Right after `p = ...` line that creates the process, here is the output:

```
/usr/bin/sh /tmp/run/launch.sh
  PID TTY          TIME CMD
29978 pts/0    00:00:01 zsh
 1178 pts/0    00:00:01 python
 1180 pts/0    00:00:00 sh <defunct>
 1181 pts/0    00:00:00 ps
None
```

Apparently the process is launched (even though `<defunct>`) and one should also note that I have a little problem passing the parameters in...

Thanks.

Comment: Are you sure the script is actually not launched? You can check that by trying to call `stat` on `/proc/child-pid-goes-here/` immediately after you call `Popen`

Comment: What is the value of command?

Comment: The value is printed at the beginning of the output `/usr/bin/sh /tmp/run/launch.sh`

Comment: At the moment I have a very simple workaround: I added `#!/usr/bin/sh` at the beginning of my `launch.sh` file and substituted the command for `/tmp/run/launch.sh`. This works. Could it be that I should not explicitly state `sh ...` if I also use `shell = True` ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I've finally found the answer to my question, thanks to `badp` and his suggestions for debugging.

From the python page on the [subprocess module](http://docs.python.org/library/subprocess.html):

> The *executable* argument specifies the program to execute. It is very seldom needed: Usually, the program to execute is defined by the args argument. If `shell=True`, the *executable* argument specifies which shell to use. On Unix, the default shell is `/bin/sh`. On Windows, the default shell is specified by the `COMSPEC` environment variable. The only reason you would need to specify `shell=True` on Windows is where the command you wish to execute is actually built in to the shell, eg `dir`, `copy`. You don’t need `shell=True` to run a batch file, nor to run a console-based executable.

Since I am on Linux and using `shell=True`, my command is in fact a list of arguments to be executed by *executable*, which defaults to `/bin/sh`. Thus the full command executed was: `/bin/sh /usr/bin/sh /tmp/run/launch.sh`... which did not work so well.

And I should have used either:

```
subprocess.Popen('/tmp/run/launch.sh', shell=True)
```

or

```
subprocess.Popen('/tmp/run/launch.sh', executable = '/usr/bin/sh', shell=True)
```

It's tricky that `shell=True` would actually modify the default *executable* value on Linux only...

Comment: Mark this as the accepted answer, then :)

(No, you don't get any rep for that.)

Comment: Rep does not really matter to me :) But there's a security: I can't accept my own answer before a few days. I've forgotten to upvote your response though, I shall correct that.

Comment: I had a related problem and saw that removing "shell=True," allowed normal passing of positional parameters to my .sh script.

It was otherwise trying to run /bin/sh -c blah.sh param1 . On my machine -c expects a string. If I ran it manually like: /bin/sh -c "blah.sh param1" it would work. Why did the /bin/sh -c get added in? Because the shell=True argument was enabled. Turn it off if you dont need it.

Answer (score 6):

Try this:

```
p = subprocess.Popen(command,
                     shell = True, #is this even needed?
                     stdin = subprocess.PIPE,
                     stdout = subprocess.PIPE,
                   # stderr = subprocess.STDOUT #uncomment if reqd
                    )
```

Tested working on Windows with the `ping` command. This lets you `communicate`, which might help you find out why the script isn't launched in the first place :)

Comment: `ping` works fine, thank you, the problem is with this particular command. Also `shell` is necessary because I need to benefit from the variables of my shell environment.